YouTube iframe embedded videos don't show up in YouTube watch history
When watching videos using the YouTube embedded player, videos don't appear in my YouTube watch history, even when I'm logged in.
Is this the intended behavior? Is there a way to change it?
<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="640" height="360"
  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?autoplay=1"
  frameborder="0">
</iframe>


No idea if that's intentional or not. https://stackoverflow.com/q/75543584/1427878 deals with the issue of views not automatically being counted - and the answer in that case apparently is, that YT doesn't count views, when you have an embed with autoplay=1 - so this could be a similar issue here, I suppose. Does anything change regarding the watch history, when you remove that, and trigger playing of the video manually?

@C3roe I just removed all query params and now it's showing up. Not sure which ones exactly are responsible and if there's a way to keep the functionality, but that's very helpful. Thanks!

Thanks to @C3roe I found the solution:
A user has to manually start playing the video via the YouTube player, otherwise it doesn't count as a view and also doesn't show up in the user's watch history.
The YouTube iframe API mentions the views, it seems to also apply to the watch history:

Note: A playback only counts toward a video's official view count if it is initiated via a native play button in the player.

